# Hyperledger fabric 1.4 how to query the transactions with good performance

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 with a go lang chaincode contract and using the java SDK to query and invoke the chaincode.

I have set CouchDB as my state database to allow good performance in querying Blockchain state db. The thing is that I want to query the transactions and these are not in the couchdb right?

My case is a bit particular but let us imagine that we have a cryptocurrency with transactions where users are transferring money between accounts, I want to get the history of:

1. All transfers done by a user A on accounts X, Y.
2. All transfers done on an account X
3. Filter on a date window and get all transfers done in this window
4. Amount transferred
5. The description of the transfer